# Embedded Questions

Tags: embedded-question

Is the following sentence correct/natural?

> The understanding for what is required of this part presupposes that one knows in which upper system it is embedded.
>
> その部品になにが求められているのかという理解は、その部品はなんの上位システムに埋め込まれているのか知っていることを前提条件します。

Or is it better to say it more simply?

> その部品になにが求められているのか理解するために、その部品は、なんの上位システムに埋め込まれているのか知っている必要があります。

Comment: As a native English speaker I find the English sentence you are trying to translate difficult to understand. I think it would help if you provided some context. For example, what is a 'part'? Is it a machine part? A grammatical construction? What is the 'upper system'?

Answer (score 1):

- I know the former is more literal, but I find it a bit difficult to understand. The latter is far easier to understand, but it has completely lost the nuance of "presuppose".
- Your second attempt looks a bit misleading because of the use of は and the comma after 部品. It almost looks like "the 部品 has to know which upper system it is embedded in". Use が and no comma.

Assuming we don't have to stick to literal translation, my recommendation is something like this:

> その部品になにが要求されているのか理解する前提として、その部品**が**何の上位システムに埋め込まれているのか(を)知っている必要があります。